# How to find character code in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to find character code of particular character in string.
For instance if I have a string

> "Hello"

How do i find the character code of all or particular characters in the string.

I see that PL/SQL has a `ASCII()` and `ASCIISTR()` functions but I could not find any character related functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  create or replace function asciistr2(s IN varchar2)
  RETURN varchar2
  IS
    result varchar2(32767) := '';
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..Length(s)
      LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(ASCII(substr(s,i,1)));
      result := result || ASCII(substr(s,i,1));
      END LOOP;
      return result;
  END;


  Select asciistr2('HELLO') from dual
```

Result: 7269767679

dbms_output

```
 72
 69
 76
 76
 79
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly would you expect? Looking at your question, it seems to me that `ASCII()` would give you what you need, see [this ASCII tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0220__Character-String-Functions/ASCIIxgetstheASCIIvalueofthecharacterx.htm). You can loop

Or are you referring to the Unicode value?

Comment: I want to iterate through a string and find all the character codes of the characters present in that string, I have yet to have a look at the link but I think ASCII() takes in a character as an argument for instance you would have to do ASCII('H') to get the character code of 'H'.

Comment: Btw I have looked at the link and most of the examples are SQL I'm looking more for PLSQL. 
For eg. in actionscript I would have done something like this 
var str:String = "HELLO";
var cCode:Number;
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  trace(str.charCodeAt(i));
}
will give result as 72, 69, 76, 76, 79

Comment: You can use almost all SQL commands in PL/SQL directly, and where you cannot, you can use them by embedding SQL.

Comment: @JulesLt: Yes, possibly, I'm not that conversant with PL/SQL, however Michael's answers comes close to what I was looking for.